# Magento : Product URL with last subcategory

Tags: url, seo

I am exporting products from Wordpress to Magento. In Wordpress url structure is like this:

```
www.mysite.com/sub-category/product/
```

but when I am opening this in Magento product url is like this:

```
www.mysite.com/category/sub-category/product/
```

Its also opening if I remove category from url:

```
www.mysite.com/product/
```

But I want subcategory in url like in Wordpress (www.mysite.com/sub-category/product/)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please be precise on what page exactly you are referring to in Magento? For instance, there are product listing page, product view page

Comment: Product view page

Answer (score 1):

Open the class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url and comment the below line

```
//if (null === $parentPath) {
//    $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
//}
//elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
    $parentPath = '';
//}
```

under function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)

and re-index the Catalog URL Rewrites from Index Management.

You should overwrite getCategoryRequestPath() function in your local codePool.

You may also use
Admin -> System -> Config -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations -> Search Engine Optimizations (set to NO)

Comment: Hi Amit 
I made changes on Mage_Catalog_Model_Url  and reindexed the URL rewrites. Now url structure is right but  Its giving me error "This webpage has a redirect loop".
Any more changes to do..?

Comment: would: You may also use Admin -> System -> Config -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations -> Search Engine Optimizations (set to NO) be the complete answer? Or does this disable many more things?